# Determine ball/hit?

Tags: rustys-real-deal-baseball

In the minigame **Cage Match**, there are levels where you have to swing the bat only when it is in the "*Strike zone*" These are part of levels 3-1 to 3-5. Is there any way to know if the ball is going to be a ball or a hit?